# Error: no match for operator<<

Tags: c++, struct

I'm training with C++ and classes. My project is composed by two file:

- main.cpp
- Date.h

**main.cpp**

```
using namespace std;

#include <iostream>
#include<Windows.h>
#include  "Date.h"

main(){
  Date date1;
  Date date2;
  cout<<"Type first date: ";
  date1.setAll();
  cout<<"type second date: ";
  date2.setAll();

  cout<<First date: "<<date1.getS();
  cout<<Second date: "<<date2.getS();
}
```

**Date.h**

```
class Date{
public:
  Date(){}
  ~Date(){system("pause");}
  void setAll();
  struct dmy{
    int day, month, year;
  };
  dmy c;
  dmy getS();
private:
  void setDay();
  void setMonth();
  void setYear();
};

void Date::setAll(){
  setDay();
  setMonth();
  setYear();
}

//all set ...

Date::dmy Date::getS(){
  return c;
}
```

I get errors in the main at

```
cout<<"First date: "<<date1.getS();
```

The error message starts with

```
Error: no match for 'operator<<' in std::operator<<
```

What does this error mean, and how can I fix it?

Due to internet restrictions on our schools' PCs I cannot copy the error message directly, here's a screen of the error message in DevC++:

[image: errors]

Comment: You should really learn how to indent code properly!

Comment: As I wrote, I'm copying the code using my tablet, isn t so easy. Have ypu ever tried?

Comment: A screen shot made with a smart phone !?

Comment: Yes "( no internet at school and blocked NIC to students account

Comment: @offtopic: you should try to copy/paste from error window of your IDE. This should work (it works in Visual Studio, it should work also in CodeBlocks).

Comment: @Jepessen: He said it once in the question _and_ the comments that he doesn't have internet at the PC he's working on ^^".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `ostream` class does not have the `operator<<` overloaded for your `struct dmy`. Therefore it does not know how to print that value. What you need without overloading the operator is something like this:

```
Date::dmy date = date1.getS();
cout<<"First date: "<< date.year << "." << date.month << "." << date.day;
```

Answer (score 1):

`date1.getS()` actually returns the struct `Date::dmy`. To make your code compile you should overload `operator<<` for `Date::dmy`